# Create a function from a select that includes another function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to create a function that outputs the integer from another function:

```
select schema.next_rowid('schema', 'table');
```

The `next_rowid()` function always outputs an integer. Using PostgreSQL 9.

Comment: Dietrich has kindly answered this question for you, but either this is more complicated than your wording suggests or you couldn't be bothered to look up "CREATE FUNCTION" in the manual. A vague knowledge of how the manuals are laid out will serve you well in future, trust me. Plenty of reference materials and examples there.

Comment: `next_rowid` seems to indicate that you somehow implemented your own sequence handling. If that is the case: **don't do it**. Use the native sequences provided by PostgreSQL

Comment: @Tudor: Don't implement your own sequences *unless* you can't live with gaps in the sequences or with numbers becoming visible out-of-order. The built-in sequences are perfect for generating unique ID values, and any home-grown implementation can't hope to match them for that; but they don't work for certain accounting applications or other uses where properties besides uniqueness are important.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable info. I searched the documentation for 2 hours, it seems I had really bad luck not finding what was in plain sight. Sometimes, it happens. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation for how to define functions?

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_pretty_function() RETURNS int AS $$
    SELECT schema.next_rowid('schema', 'table');
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```